# Redis: Find keys matching a pattern

Tags: redis, pattern-matching

How I can find keys matching a pattern like this:

Eg:

I have some keys:

`abc:parent1`

`abc:parent2`

`abc:parent1:child1`

`abc:parent2:child2`

How can I find only

`abc:parent1`

`abc:parent2`

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Keys is specifically noted as a command not to be run in production due to the way it works. What you need here is to create an index of your keys. Use a `set` for storing the key names of the pattern you want. When you add a new we key, add the name of it to the set. For example:

```
Set abc:parent1:child1 breakfast
Sadd abc:parent1:index abc:parent1
```

Then when you need the list:

```
Smembers abc:parent1:index
```

Will give you the list, without the penalties and problems associated with using the "evil" keys command. Additionally you would remove an entry with `sremove` on key deletion. You also get as a benefit the ability to know how many keys are in the index with a single call.

If you absolutely, positively, MUST avoid using an index use `SCAN` instead of keys. The only time you should even consider keys is if you are running a debug slave where the only process using it is your debugging process.

Comment: I don't quite understand how this is supposed to work. In your example, should it in reality be: `set abc:parent1:child1 breakfast` and then `sadd abc:parent1 child1`?

Comment: No, because the OP only wanted to the level of parent1 not child.

Comment: I misunderstood the question, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: im still confused. OP wants to find "abc:parent1 abc:parent2" shouldnt it be sadd abc abc:parent1 and sadd abc abc:parent2 and smembers abc?

Comment: @TheRealBill could you please be more descriptive in your examples? :) I don't really understand it? How to fetch all keys and values with the pattern `abc:parent1` ?

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Interesting that "Keys is specifically noted as a command not to be run in production due to the way it works." Would you be able to provide a link to the source that says this?

Comment: @SungCho https://redis.io/commands/keys

```Warning: consider KEYS as a command that should only be used in production environments with extreme care. It may ruin performance when it is executed against large databases. This command is intended for debugging and special operations, such as changing your keyspace layout. Don't use KEYS in your regular application code. If you're looking for a way to find keys in a subset of your keyspace, consider using SCAN or sets.```

Comment: It seems there are some naming confusions in the provided example and more clear version of it can look like this:
`SET abc:parent1:child1 breakfast` `SADD abc:parent:index abc:parent1` `SET abc:parent2:child1 dinner`  `SADD abc:parent:index abc:parent2` `SMEMBERS abc:parent:index`. Output will be `abc:parent1` and `abc:parent2`

Answer (score 31):

Command ***KEYS pattern***
will help you for the same, if it is not a production environment. (Never use keys in production)

ex:

```
redis> MSET one 1 two 2 three 3 four 4
OK
redis> KEYS *o*
1) "two"
2) "one"
3) "four"
```

For your specific example, the below command will work:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> keys *parent[0-9]
1) "abc:parent2"
2) "abc:parent1"
```

Here's [the detailed description of the command](http://redis.io/commands/keys).

**Update:** Though the suggestion above helps you get the desired output, the redis *KEYS* command is evil as the others mentioned. *KEYS* is blocking and can consume a lot of RAM while preparing the response.

> Don't use KEYS in your regular application code. If you're looking for a way to find keys in a subset of your keyspace, consider using SCAN or sets.

Thanks The Real Bill and Itamar, I got a better understanding.

Comment: How do you do with `permission:/url1/id/sub:write` and `permission:/url1/id:write` to match only `permission:/url1/[^/]+`

Comment: @ItamarHaber `KEYS` is *not* evil.  Using it in production code is.  As a development tool it's invaluable.